# Inline CSS is not working with Mpdf

Tags: php, css, symfony, mpdf

I am using the Mpdf in symfony. I have installed the mpdf through composer like:

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

After that require the Mpdf.php in `autoload.php`.

Then use the code for mpdf is:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = '<p style="color:red;">PDF Generating...</p>';
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('demo.pdf', 'F');
```

CSS is not affecting on the HTML. When I'm using the style on tag then it's working fine.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = '<style>p{color:red;}</style><p>PDF Generating...</p>';
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('demo.pdf', 'F');
```

When I try to use the CSS with class or ID then also not affecting.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = '<style>p.text-color{color:red;}</style><p class="text-color">PDF Generating...</p>';
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('demo.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: When the page loads, check if the source is exactly as you need it. Code might need to be escaped. Only have a little php experience but that springs to mind. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php I think it's the double quotes that's screwing you over

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the style tag you can do it as follow:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
```

So write your CSS first then your html that was working for me the last time.

https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html

Comment: I also tried this solution. It's working but only with HTML tags not with Class/ID.